# Did someone make a QFT based on matrix mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I usually read a lot of posts saying that [matrix mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics) is kind of useless nowadays, but some of its properties might be useful for understanding other things.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98049/example-of-application-of-creation-annihilation-operators-in-matrix-form?rq=1), or [else](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242243/matrix-for-ladder-operators), ...

Answer (score 3):

Your title is at variance with the body of your question, except in a broader sense thrown at the reader to guess. I have no idea *how* you got the erroneous impression that MM is "kind of useless nowadays". It is deeply unsound. To the extent that wave mechanics is a different facet of the unified abstract description of QM established by Dirac, the other facet being WM, you are really talking about the *same thing*. If your QM course were any good, you were taught the [number basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Matrix_representation) for the [oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Analytical_questions).

The algebraic solution of the quantum oscillator devised by Dirac yields explicitly the number basis formalism of Heisenberg's original MM. Every time you discuss number states (instead of solving Hermite's differential equation for WM), you are  utilizing the basic principles of MM. Since QFT, a relativistic repackaging of an infinity of oscillators,  is *defined* through creation and annihilation operators, instead of Hermite functions, you are essentially applying MM language.

Here is my own cultural explanation of *how* you got such a wrong-minded misimpression in the first place. The dichotomy between MM and WM is magnificently false, but common. It took root, now largely moldered, in the 20s and 30s. At that time, physicists were more familiar with differential equations than matrix techniques, and had not yet incorporated Hilbert space into their educational systems—and one might argue chemists still haven't. So there are all these comical contemporary accounts of relief in the community at the advent of WM, since physicists could at last (!) solve eigenvalue wave equation problems; and eschew operator and matrix problems, now, of course, the darling of any decent theorist.

In practical, e.g. chemistry, contexts, large atoms, etc., solving wave equations, even numerically (oh, the irony!), favors WM.

In any case, "nowadays", as you put it, Fock space is really more reminiscent of MM than WM. (And, of course, QFT is defined in the intermediate interaction picture, squarely in-between the Heisenberg and Schroedinger pictures.)